# While saving file on system directory getting error as Internal Server Error in flask

Tags: python, flask, file-handling

I'am creating a web app to download excel data from athena and save it on users system using flask framework.
The code is working fine when the excel data getting downloaded into root directory, now problem is when I'm giving an option to user select folder using asksaveasfile() method and download excel on their local directory then its giving error as "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pyathena import connect
import os 
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import matplotlib
from openpyxl import Workbook
from IPython import get_ipython
from datetime import datetime
from flask import send_file
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
import getpass
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from flask import request, redirect, url_for,flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os




app = Flask(__name__)


app = Flask(__name__)

filename = ''

def colorExcle(loc):
    wb = Workbook()
    location = loc


    redFill = PatternFill(start_color='99e6ff',
                    end_color='99e6ff',
                    fill_type='solid')

    ws = wb.active
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(location)

    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=11).value = 'UserName'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=12).value = 'Result'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=13).value = 'Coding Time in min'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=14).value = 'QC1 By'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=15).value = 'QC1 Result'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=16).value = 'QC1 Time in min'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=17).value = 'Comments'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=18).value = 'KM'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=19).value = 'Rework'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=20).value = 'QC2 Time in min'
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=21).value = 'QC2 Results'



    sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=2).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=3).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=4).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=5).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=6).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=7).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=8).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=9).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=10).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=11).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=12).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=13).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=14).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=15).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=16).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=17).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=18).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=19).fill = redFill

    sheet.cell(row=1,column=20).fill = redFill
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=21).fill = redFill
    wb.save(location)   

    return render_template('index.html') 





@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def index():

    if "HAD" in request.form:

        projectTag = request.form.get('projectTag')
        region = request.form.get('region')

        if request.method == "POST":
            region = request.form.get("region", None)
            if region!=None:

                conn = connect(aws_access_key_id='AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
                    aws_secret_access_key='VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV',
                    s3_staging_dir='s3://CVD-analytics-athena-stating-dir/',
                    region_name='us-west-1')

                cursor = conn.cursor()
                now = datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
                excelName=region.upper()+"_"+projectTag+"_"+now
                wb = Workbook()
                ws = wb.active

                data1 = r"C:\\Users\\"+ getpass.getuser()+"\\Downloads\\"+excelName+'.xlsx'



                wb.save(data1)
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(data1)
                sheet = wb['Sheet']
                data =  pd.read_sql("SELECT * from table;",conn)
                data.to_excel(data1)

                filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
                data2 = data.to_excel(data1)
                filename.write(data2)
                return colorExcle(data1)
                return render_template('index.html', projectTag,region)


    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])



@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Quite new to python and flask.
Descriptive code could help me more.

Comment: You can't run tkinter from a web server.

Comment: okay...
But when I am not using tkinter to save file by specifying path then also I'm getting the same error